# how to test the speed of visual tree rendering in silverlight?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, performance, dispatcher, visual-tree

For example, I create a Canvas that contains a big amount of Shapes like this:

```
var canvas = CreateCanvasThatContainsShapes();
```

Then I add all the canvas to main page:

```
layoutRoot.Content = canvas;
```

It takes not so much time for those two lines of code to run, but it take a while for all the shapes to show up on the screen, and the UI will be unresponsive for a while.

In WPF, I can test the visual tree rendering time by doing something like this:

```
//create logic tree and add it to main page
stopWatch.Start();
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
stopWatch.Stop();
//Show the ellipsed time
}),DispatcherPriority.Loaded);
```

This way, the Stopwatch starts after the logic tree is created and stops after the visual tree is rendered(loaded).

But in silverlight, there is no DispatcherPriority, then how can I do the similar thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event that you can use to help determine the time taken to render to screen; [LayoutUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.layoutupdated.aspx). This event is fired whenever a layout parse completes. Start your timer before you set your `layoutRoot.Content`, and stop it when the event fires. This tells you how long the render process took.

Another useful event to look out for is [CompositionTarget.Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering.aspx), this event fires each time the UI is rendered. You should find that this event fires very often, however when you add your complex visual tree, you will see a gap in the stream of events.

Comment: sadly, the LayoutUpdated event did not work out, dont know why yet.